# Add package routes into main app routes with Express

Tags: angularjs, express

im writing my own MEAN stack. I want to structure it in a horizontal architecture similar to how mean.io does theirs. Each package has its own server and public folder with its own routes.

I have a server.js which is my main express file at the root level. When I start things with npm start I would like to have each package register its own routes / mount its own routes on my main app instance. For some reason though im getting express errors when I try to do this.

Can anyone advise me? Thanks so much.   https://github.com/peb7268/LMFM.git

Comment: Answered my own question. Was mounting the default path / incorrectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the submodule / package ( in this case users ) I needed to mount things differently:

```
var express         = require('express');
var router          = express.Router();

var Users = function(){
    var self        = this;
    self._name      = 'users';
    console.log('initializing ' + self._name);

    router.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res){
        res.send('finding '+ self._name);
    });
}

module.exports = {'router': router, 'instance': new Users()};
```

Instead of router.route('/users');

Because when you do app.use('/users', router); the '/', default path will collide with '/users' in the sub module.